# Object array in a class C++ (embarcadero)

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have an issue with setting up an Object Array in my class:

2 pages: `Element.H` and `LinePiece.h`.

Element.H contains the following code:

```
class element
{
public:
element() {};

AnsiString ON;          //order nummer
AnsiString MO;          //order merk
AnsiString SN;          //element nummer
AnsiString RS;          //element afwerking
AnsiString OW;          //wapeningspatroon
AnsiString CN;          //element calculation number
int el_length;          //element lengte
int el_width;           //element hoogte
int el_beginX;          //element beginpunt
int el_concrete_height; //element hoogte beton
int el_iso_height;      //element isolatie hoogte
AnsiString el_weight;   //element gewicht
LinePiece arrayLP[];    // !! This isn't  correct, How can I solve this? !!

element(AnsiString a_ON, AnsiString a_MO, AnsiString a_SN, AnsiString a_RS, AnsiString a_OW,
AnsiString a_CN, int a_elLength, int a_elWidth, int a_elBeginX, int a_elConcreteHeight,
int a_elIsoHeight, AnsiString a_elWeight)
{
    ON = a_ON;
    MO = a_MO;
    SN = a_SN;
    RS = a_RS;
    OW = a_OW;
    CN = a_CN;
    el_length = a_elLength;
    el_width = a_elWidth;
    el_beginX = a_elBeginX;
    el_concrete_height = a_elConcreteHeight;
    el_iso_height = a_elIsoHeight;
    el_weight = a_elWeight;

};
};
```

LinePiece.h contains the following code:

```
 class LinePiece
{
public:
LinePiece() {};

AnsiString Type;
int ElementNr;
int Status;
int X, Y;

LinePiece(AnsiString a_type, int a_elementnr, int a_status, int a_x, int a_y)
{
    Type = a_type;
    ElementNr = a_elementnr;
    Status = a_status;
    X = a_x;
    Y = a_y;
}

};
```

As you can notice in the element I want to create an Object array with some values in it.

But When I'm trying to create one it gives like 50 errors about multiple declarations.
Some examples:
- E2238 Multiple declaration for 'char_traits::int_type'
- E2344 Earlier declaration for 'char_traits::int type'
- E2238 Multiple declaration for 'char_traits::assign(wchar_t&,const wchar_t &)'

So is it possible to use an objectarray in another class?

Comment: You *do* know about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Oh, and none of the errors you mention have anything to do with the array. Please clarify your question, are you asking about the array, or about the errors? Because those seems to be two different issues and so should have to different questions.

Comment: Well when I remove the line 'LinePiece arrayLP[];' they dont appear. Even when I create an array like: int numberArray[]; it works.

Comment: It's really hard to say anything (besides that you can't really have arrays without a size) without a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the complete error output.

Comment: Ok, very simple, Is it possible to use an object Array in another class? And if it is, how do I get it working?

Comment: Are you including `LinePiece.h` in Element.h ?

Comment: When I include LinePiece.h it complains about multiple and earlier declarations of 'LinePiece'. I do include it multiple times so thats probably the problem....

Comment: I've solved it, I just had to forward declare it instead of including the header file, I read about it in this article: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
LinePiece arrayLP[];
```

by this:

```
LinePiece* arrayLP;
```

or by this:

```
std::vector<LinePiece> arrayLP;
```

When use pointer don't forget to allocate memory in constructor and deallocate in destructor.
When use vector, dont forget about #include .

And like @Joachim Pileborg suggested - check about STL vectors and about STL collections.